# rendering node $content but not all $content is there

Tags: nodes, theming

node `$content` variable does not contain all node elements

On my local test site the `$content` variable contains around 10 elements which I used to build my custom node template.

but now on the live site I only have 2 elements in the `$content` array.

I can't figure out why and looked everywhere but can't find where `$content` is set and or why the the other 'elements' of my node are not loaded in the `$content` variable.

using the normal 'view' all content is available.
using my `node--teaser.tpl.php` not on the live site.

Both sites have the same modules enabled and are using similar node types.

Comment: Are they using the same theme?

Comment: Check permissions...if they aren't set identically, users might not be able to see all the fields in your node....also there is a difference between normal and teaser views so make sure the theme isn't doing this on purpose.

Comment: Did you check your display options for that content type to make sure that those fields are set to display in teaser mode?

Comment: yes they use the same theme, versions and everything. view is set to a custom view which i copyed using the features module. checking permissions and display fields / views now.

Comment: Thnx @landing The fields where not set to 'visible' in the teaser of the node content display settings.
If you post your answer below I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: @FLY - No prob. Added my comment as the an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your display options for that content type to make sure that those fields are set to display in teaser mode.

Drupal 6: `admin/content/node-type/NAME-OF-CONTENT-TYPE/display`

Drupal 7: `admin/structure/types/manage/NAME-OF-CONTENT-TYPE/display`